# Android: can anyone give example how to load map using google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I want to load map in my app, but not able to interpret help from google developers documentation.

Comment: Check this link if you have not gone through.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: Try to search in google first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have Recently Update May and Follow this Steps hope helps you in short

`step [1]`  Update your `sdk` and   and check  `Google Play service`

`step [2]` goto  sdk path Like   `C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\google`
and import Google Play Service Libray in your `workspace`

`step [3]` add `library` in Your Project

`step [4]` in your xml  put Like

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/includefooter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativetop" />
```

`step [5]` in Activity   like

```
    public class YourActivi extends FragmentActivity {
....
GoogleMap mapView;

mapView = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();
}
```

step [6] in Manifest

```
  <permission
        android:name="com.tixe.Activity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="YourPackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="yourKey" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

also check Require Permission.

Answer (score 1):

When  i was integrating the same in my android app, that time this integration made me sick. Following proper steps from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ helps me a lot. Important thing to remember don't forget to install Google Api's from Android SDK Manager.